# When using a render texture to render game, how can I get more control of what to render?

Tags: unity

I use a render texture to render my entire game, I lower the size to get a "pixelation" effect. I've run into the issue now where I need to render some things in world space that should not be pixelated, like HP bars, can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried using the [`Culling Mask`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-cullingMask.html)?

Comment: I have, there are a few issues with rendering 2 render textures on top of each other. best case u can render using a second camera to a second higher res texture, but u get some unwanted artifacts here and there since u need to set background type to Uninitialized.